# Pattern.quote adds \\Q and \\E to the string java

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

I am trying to replace text with special chars (that require me to Pattern.quote them) with a lowercase version of that text but the Pattern.quote function sometimes adds \Q and \E to the beginning and the end of the text so the replace method doesn't find it.
The code i am using is:

```
bigText = bigText.replaceFirst(Pattern.quote(text),text.toLowerCase());
```

Is there a way to lose those chars?

Comment: Could you give an example of `text` and what you'd want to match with it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding `\Q` and `\E` is exactly what `Pattern.quote()` does! Why would you not want that?

If you need to quote only some characters of that string, then you must do so manually.

Comment: If so, it cannot be replaced as i wanted. Also - why sometimes it does work (meaning it doesn't add those chars)?

Comment: Reading the source of OpenJDK 1.6 shows only one case where those are not added and that is if the input is `null` (in which case a NPE will be thrown). And as far as I know this is how it always worked.

Comment: Yea, I've done some research and you are right about that. I guess i should explore my code deeper to see why it isn't replaced...